# Compile Shotdetect on CentOS 7

Tags: compilation, ffmpeg, centos7, libavcodec

I'm migrating a service from a Debian server to a CentOS 7 one.

The service needs the Shotdetect command ([github](https://github.com/johmathe/Shotdetect) , [official site](http://johmathe.name/shotdetect.html)).

I could not make it work on CentOS though I followed all steps:

1. Compile ffmpeg [compilation guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos)

   ```
   # ffmpeg
   ffmpeg version git-2015-08-21-7a806c6 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
     built with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC) 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)
     configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --disable-libmp3lame --disable-libopus --disable-libvorbis --disable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --disable-libx265 --disable-lzma
     libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
     libavcodec     56. 58.100 / 56. 58.100
     libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
     libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
     libavfilter     5. 36.100 /  5. 36.100
     libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
     libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
     libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
   Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
   usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
   ```

   2. Install needed packages

      ```
      # yum install gd-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-devel clang libvpx libvorbis
      ```
   3. Add **pthread** in the CMakeList file, in TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES, because it throws an *lpthread missing in linker* error
   4. Compile Shotdetect

      ```
      # FFMPEG_DIR="/root/ffmpeg_build"  ./compile.sh cmd
      ```

5.Lost in contemplation

```
-- avformat library found: /root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a
-- avcodec library found: /root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a
-- avutil library found: /root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavutil.a
-- swscale library found: /root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libswscale.a
Found all FFmpeg libraries in /root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a;/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavdevice.a;/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a;/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavutil.a;/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libswscale.a.
-- Found GD: /usr/lib64/libgd.so
Found libgd: /usr/lib64/libgd.so;/usr/lib64/libpng.so;/usr/lib64/libz.so;/usr/lib64/libjpeg.so in /usr/include
Found libxml2: /usr/lib64/libxml2.so in /usr/include/libxml2
Found libxslt: /usr/lib64/libxslt.so in /usr/include
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /root/Shotdetect-master/build
[ 71%] Built target shotdetect
Linking CXX executable shotdetect-cmd
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacdec.o): in the function « fdk_aac_decode_frame »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacdec.c:323: undefined reference to « aacDecoder_Fill »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacdec.c:329: undefined reference to « aacDecoder_DecodeFrame »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacdec.o): in the function « get_stream_info »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacdec.c:88: undefined reference to « aacDecoder_GetStreamInfo »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacdec.o): in the function « fdk_aac_decode_close »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacdec.c:201: undefined reference to « aacDecoder_Close »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacdec.o): in the function « fdk_aac_decode_init »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacdec.c:214: undefined reference to « aacDecoder_Open »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacdec.c:221: undefined reference to « aacDecoder_ConfigRaw »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacdec.c:228: undefined reference to « aacDecoder_SetParam »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacdec.c:252: undefined reference to « aacDecoder_SetParam »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacdec.c:270: undefined reference to « aacDecoder_SetParam »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacdec.c:277: undefined reference to « aacDecoder_SetParam »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacdec.c:284: undefined reference to « aacDecoder_SetParam »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacdec.o):/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacdec.c:291: encore plus de références indéfinies suivent vers « aacDecoder_SetParam »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacdec.o): in the function « fdk_aac_decode_init »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacdec.c:261: undefined reference to « aacDecoder_AncDataInit »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacdec.o): in the function « fdk_aac_decode_flush »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacdec.c:367: undefined reference to « aacDecoder_SetParam »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacenc.o): in the function « aac_encode_close »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:97: undefined reference to « aacEncClose »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacenc.o): in the function « aac_encode_frame »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:357: undefined reference to « aacEncEncode »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacenc.o): in the function « aac_encode_init »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:114: undefined reference to « aacEncOpen »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:123: undefined reference to « aacEncoder_SetParam »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:130: undefined reference to « aacEncoder_SetParam »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:138: undefined reference to « aacEncoder_SetParam »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:172: undefined reference to « aacEncoder_SetParam »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:179: undefined reference to « aacEncoder_SetParam »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacenc.o):/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:197: encore plus de références indéfinies suivent vers « aacEncoder_SetParam »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacenc.o): in the function « aac_encode_init »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:276: undefined reference to « aacEncEncode »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:282: undefined reference to « aacEncInfo »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): in the function « X264_frame »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:260: undefined reference to « x264_picture_init »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:262: undefined reference to « x264_bit_depth »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): in the function « reconfig_encoder »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:246: undefined reference to « x264_encoder_reconfig »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): in the function « X264_frame »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:283: undefined reference to « x264_encoder_encode »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:289: undefined reference to « x264_encoder_delayed_frames »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:283: undefined reference to « x264_encoder_encode »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): in the function « reconfig_encoder »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:173: undefined reference to « x264_encoder_reconfig »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:178: undefined reference to « x264_encoder_reconfig »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:185: undefined reference to « x264_encoder_reconfig »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:205: undefined reference to « x264_encoder_reconfig »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:211: undefined reference to « x264_encoder_reconfig »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o):/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:191: encore plus de références indéfinies suivent vers « x264_encoder_reconfig »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): in the function « X264_init_static »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:806: undefined reference to « x264_bit_depth »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): in the function « X264_close »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:339: undefined reference to « x264_encoder_close »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): in the function « X264_init »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:413: undefined reference to « x264_param_default »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:418: undefined reference to « x264_param_default_preset »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:440: undefined reference to « x264_param_parse »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:470: undefined reference to « x264_param_parse »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:514: undefined reference to « x264_levels »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:516: undefined reference to « x264_levels »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:540: undefined reference to « x264_param_parse »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:541: undefined reference to « x264_param_parse »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:542: undefined reference to « x264_param_parse »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:543: undefined reference to « x264_param_parse »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:601: undefined reference to « x264_param_apply_fastfirstpass »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:651: undefined reference to « x264_param_apply_profile »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:703: undefined reference to « x264_param_parse »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:705: undefined reference to « x264_param_parse »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:717: undefined reference to « x264_param_parse »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:735: undefined reference to « x264_encoder_open_148 »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:744: undefined reference to « x264_encoder_headers »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): in the function « opus_decode_subpacket »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:379: undefined reference to « swr_is_initialized »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): in the function « opus_decode_frame »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:220: undefined reference to « swr_is_initialized »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): in the function « opus_init_resample »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:161: undefined reference to « swr_init »
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:167: undefined reference to « swr_convert »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): in the function « opus_decode_frame »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:234: undefined reference to « swr_convert »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): in the function « opus_flush_resample »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:115: undefined reference to « swr_convert »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): in the function « opus_decode_subpacket »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:411: undefined reference to « swr_close »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): in the function « opus_decode_flush »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:614: undefined reference to « swr_close »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): in the function « opus_decode_close »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:638: undefined reference to « swr_free »
/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): in the function « opus_decode_init »:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:705: undefined reference to « swr_alloc »
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [shotdetect-cmd] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/shotdetect-cmd.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've done a lot of research about the above errors but I didn't find any clue.

How to compile successfully Shotdetect on CentOS7?

## Thanks to tryp here is a working CMakelist file:

```
# CMake integration by Christian Frisson
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(shotdetect)

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang++")
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")


# Get git version information for automatic embedding in version string:

include(GetGitRevisionDescription)
get_git_head_revision(GIT_REFSPEC GIT_SHA1)
# Take the first 12 characters of the SHA1 as short identifier:
STRING(SUBSTRING ${GIT_SHA1} 0 11 GIT_SHA1_SHORT)
configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/version.cc.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cc" @ONLY)
list(APPEND SOURCES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cc" src/version.h)

# Miscellaneous compilation options:

OPTION(USE_WXWIDGETS "Compile GUI app with wxWidgets, otherwise commandline app" ON)
OPTION(USE_POSTGRESQL "Compile with PostgreSQL support" OFF)

# Dependency: pkg-config (required if cross-compiling with MXE)

IF ( MINGW AND CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)
    FIND_PACKAGE (PkgConfig)
    IF(NOT PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
        MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "pkgconfig required for cross-compiling with MXE for windows")
    ENDIF()
    SET(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE ${PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE} CACHE STRING "pkg-config")
ENDIF()

# Dependency: FFmpeg (required)

FIND_PACKAGE( FFmpeg )
IF ( MINGW AND CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)
    PKG_CHECK_MODULES (FFMPEG_PKG REQUIRED libavcodec libavfilter libavutil libavdevice libavformat libavformat libswscale)
    IF (FFMPEG_PKG_FOUND)
        MESSAGE( "FFmpeg cflags found through pkg-config: ${FFMPEG_PKG_CFLAGS}" )
        MESSAGE( "FFmpeg ldflags found through pkg-config: ${FFMPEG_PKG_LDFLAGS}" )
        STRING(REGEX REPLACE ";" " " FFMPEG_PKG_CFLAGS "${FFMPEG_PKG_CFLAGS}")
        SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${FFMPEG_PKG_CFLAGS}")
        SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${FFMPEG_PKG_CFLAGS}")
        SET(FFMPEG_LIBRARIES ${FFMPEG_LIBRARY} ${FFMPEG_PKG_LDFLAGS})
        MESSAGE("FFMPEG_LIBRARIES ${FFMPEG_LIBRARIES}")
    ELSE (FFMPEG_PKG_FOUND)
        MESSAGE( FATAL_ERROR "FFmpeg cflags/ldflags not found through pkg-config." )
    ENDIF (FFMPEG_PKG_FOUND)
ENDIF()
IF(FFMPEG_LIBAVFORMAT_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "avformat library found: ${FFMPEG_LIBAVFORMAT_LIBRARIES}")
ELSE()
    MESSAGE(STATUS "avformat library not found.")
ENDIF()
IF(FFMPEG_LIBAVCODEC_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "avcodec library found: ${FFMPEG_LIBAVCODEC_LIBRARIES}")
ELSE()
    MESSAGE(STATUS "avcodec library not found.")
ENDIF()
IF(FFMPEG_LIBAVUTIL_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "avutil library found: ${FFMPEG_LIBAVUTIL_LIBRARIES}")
ELSE()
    MESSAGE(STATUS "avutil library not found.")
ENDIF()
IF(FFMPEG_LIBSWSCALE_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "swscale library found: ${FFMPEG_LIBSWSCALE_LIBRARIES}")
ELSE()
    MESSAGE(STATUS "swscale library not found.")
ENDIF()
IF(FFMPEG_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR} ${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    SET(FFMPEG_LIBRARIES "${FFMPEG_LIBRARIES};/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libswresample.a;/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libx264.a;/lib64/libdl.so.2;/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libfdk-aac.a;/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libswresample.a")
    MESSAGE("Found all FFmpeg libraries in ${FFMPEG_LIBRARIES}.")
ELSE()
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Some FFmpeg libraries are missing.")
ENDIF()

# Dependency: GD (required)

FIND_PACKAGE(GD REQUIRED)
IF ( MINGW AND CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)
    EXEC_PROGRAM(${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}/bin/gdlib-config ARGS "--cflags" OUTPUT_VARIABLE GD_PKG_CFLAGS) 
    EXEC_PROGRAM(${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}/bin/gdlib-config ARGS "--libs" OUTPUT_VARIABLE GD_PKG_LDFLAGS)
    MESSAGE( "gd cflags found through gdlib-config: ${GD_PKG_CFLAGS}" )
    MESSAGE( "gd ldflags found through gdlib-config: ${GD_PKG_LDFLAGS}" )
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GD_PKG_CFLAGS}")
    SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${GD_PKG_CFLAGS}")
    SET(GD_LIBRARIES ${GD_LIBRARY} ${GD_PKG_LDFLAGS})
    MESSAGE("GD_LIBRARIES ${GD_LIBRARIES}")
ENDIF()
IF(GD_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GD_INCLUDE_DIR})
    MESSAGE("Found libgd: ${GD_LIBRARIES} in ${GD_INCLUDE_DIR}")
ELSE()
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Couldn't find libgd")
ENDIF()

# Dependency: libxml2 (required)

FIND_PACKAGE(LibXml2 2.7 REQUIRED)
IF ( MINGW AND CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)
    PKG_CHECK_MODULES (LIBXML2_PKG REQUIRED libxml-2.0)
    IF (LIBXML2_PKG_FOUND)
        MESSAGE( "LibXml2 cflags found through pkg-config: ${LIBXML2_PKG_CFLAGS}" )
        MESSAGE( "LibXml2 ldflags found through pkg-config: ${LIBXML2_PKG_LDFLAGS}" )
        STRING(REGEX REPLACE ";" " " LIBXML2_PKG_CFLAGS "${LIBXML2_PKG_CFLAGS}")
        SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${LIBXML2_PKG_CFLAGS}")
        SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${LIBXML2_PKG_CFLAGS}")
        SET(LIBXML2_LIBRARIES ${LIBXML2_LIBRARY} ${LIBXML2_PKG_LDFLAGS})
        MESSAGE("LIBXML2_LIBRARIES ${LIBXML2_LIBRARIES}")
    ELSE (LIBXML2_PKG_FOUND)
        MESSAGE( FATAL_ERROR "LibXml2 cflags/ldflags not found through pkg-config." )
    ENDIF (LIBXML2_PKG_FOUND)
ENDIF()
IF(LIBXML2_FOUND)
    MESSAGE("Found libxml2: ${LIBXML2_LIBRARIES} in ${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR})
ELSE()
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Couldn't find libxml2")
ENDIF()

# Dependency: libxslt (required)

FIND_PACKAGE(LibXslt REQUIRED)
IF(LIBXSLT_FOUND)
    MESSAGE("Found libxslt: ${LIBXSLT_LIBRARIES} in ${LIBXSLT_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${LIBXSLT_INCLUDE_DIR})
ELSE()
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Couldn't find libxslt")
ENDIF()

# Dependency: wxWidgets (optional)
IF(USE_WXWIDGETS)
    FIND_PACKAGE(wxWidgets)# COMPONENTS core base)
    IF(wxWidgets_FOUND)
        MESSAGE("Found wxWidgets: ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES} in ${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
        INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
        ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DWXWIDGETS)
        INCLUDE("${wxWidgets_USE_FILE}")
    ELSE()
        MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Couldn't find wxWidgets. Set USE_WXWIDGETS to OFF or install wxWidgets.")
    ENDIF()
ENDIF()

# Dependency: PostgreSQL (optional)
IF(USE_POSTGRESQL)
    FIND_PACKAGE(PostgreSQL)
    IF(PostgreSQL_FOUND)
        MESSAGE("Found PostgreSQL: ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES} in ${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
        INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIR})
    ELSE()
        MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Couldn't find PostgreSQL. Set USE_POSTGRESQL to OFF or install PostgreSQL.")
    ENDIF()
ENDIF()

# shotdetect

SET(TARGET_NAME "shotdetect")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(.)

# shotdetect library

SET(${TARGET_NAME}_LIBRARY_SRCS src/film.cc src/graph.cc src/image.cc src/shot.cc src/xml.cc)
SET(${TARGET_NAME}_LIBRARY_HDRS  src/film.h src/graph.h src/image.h src/shot.h src/xml.h)
IF(USE_POSTGRESQL)
    SET(${TARGET_NAME}_LIBRARY_SRCS ${${TARGET_NAME}_LIBRARY_SRCS} src/bdd.cc)
    SET(${TARGET_NAME}_LIBRARY_HDRS ${${TARGET_NAME}_LIBRARY_HDRS} src/bdd.h)
ENDIF()
ADD_LIBRARY(${TARGET_NAME} ${${TARGET_NAME}_LIBRARY_SRCS} ${${TARGET_NAME}_LIBRARY_HDRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${TARGET_NAME} ${FFMPEG_LIBRARIES} ${LIBXML2_LIBRARIES} ${LIBXSLT_LIBRARIES} ${GD_LIBRARIES} "pthread" "m" "z")
IF(USE_WXWIDGETS AND wxWidgets_FOUND)
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${TARGET_NAME} ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
ENDIF()
IF(USE_POSTGRESQL AND PostgreSQL_FOUND)
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${TARGET_NAME} ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARY})
ENDIF()

# shotdetect application: gui or commandline

IF(APPLE)
    SET(APP_TYPE "MACOSX_BUNDLE")
ELSEIF(WIN32)
    SET(APP_TYPE "WIN32")
ENDIF()

IF(USE_WXWIDGETS AND wxWidgets_FOUND)
    LIST(APPEND ${TARGET_NAME}_GUI_SRCS src/main.cc src/ui/dialog_help.cc src/ui/dialog_shotdetect.cc src/ui/process_video_thread.cc)
    LIST(APPEND ${TARGET_NAME}_GUI_HDRS src/ui/dialog_help.h src/ui/dialog_shotdetect.h src/ui/process_video_thread.h)
    ADD_EXECUTABLE(${TARGET_NAME}-gui ${APP_TYPE} ${SOURCES} ${${TARGET_NAME}_GUI_SRCS} ${${TARGET_NAME}_GUI_HDRS})
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${TARGET_NAME}-gui ${TARGET_NAME})
    # Make this target optional to install:
    SET(TARGETS_TO_INSTALL ${TARGET_NAME}-gui)
ELSE()
    LIST(APPEND ${TARGET_NAME}_COMMANDLINE_SRCS src/commandline.cc)
    ADD_EXECUTABLE(${TARGET_NAME}-cmd ${SOURCES} ${${TARGET_NAME}_COMMANDLINE_SRCS})
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${TARGET_NAME}-cmd ${TARGET_NAME})
    # Make this target optional to install:
    SET(TARGETS_TO_INSTALL ${TARGET_NAME}-cmd)
ENDIF()


# Routines for installing shotdetect.
# Taken from official documentation (http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:install)
install( 
    TARGETS ${TARGETS_TO_INSTALL}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/static
)
```

the built binary will be in the *built* directory, you can move there and execute

```
make install
```

to make the binary system wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked this similar issue ? [Linking libavcodec and libavformat: Undefined references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366433/linking-libavcodec-and-libavformat-undefined-references)

They suggest to add some libraries :

```
-lswresample -lm -lz
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed the **TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES to this: TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${TARGET_NAME} ${FFMPEG_LIBRARIES} ${LIBXML2_LIBRARIES} ${LIBXSLT_LIBRARIES} ${GD_LIBRARIES} "pthread" "m" "z" "/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libswresample.a")** and appended missing libs too *SET(FFMPEG_LIBRARIES "${FFMPEG_LIBRARIES};/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libswresample.a;/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libx264.a;/lib64/libdl.so.2;/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libfdk-aac.a")*